# WSO2 ESB Aggregate mediator with HTTP status

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I was curious about the aggregate mediator, what would the `$axis2:HTTP_SC` provide in the `on-complete` sequence of aggregate mediator? How can I get the HTTP Status code for each response separately or within my aggregated response?

Comment: want to read the HTTP_SC in on-complete sequence? could you explain the requirement

Comment: Since I have invoked 2 or 3 endpoints for example in Clone mediator, in the on-complete sequence, I want to check each HTTP_SC of each response.